# filter search results from a ThinkingSphinx search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

I would like to allow user to search for other users by typing a few keywords in Search box (with ThinkingSphinx as back-end).

After the server returned the search results and display it on View, I want users to be able to click on a dropdown, check on checkboxes to narrow down the results without resubmmitting the query.

Is there a way to filter previous search results WITHOUT having to submit a new query with additional keywords/facets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there's not - well, not reliably. You could filter search results manually, but Sphinx paginates results, so you're not generally dealing with the full set of initial matches, which means there could be valid filtered responses you won't see.

To keep things reliable, it's best to run the query against Sphinx again.